# Is it correct to say "He is lying passing out on the floor"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We can have some adjectives standing after "**lie**".

For example, "*he is lying **awake** on the bed*" and "*the dog is lying **dead** on the floor*"

Now, "**to pass out**" means "**to become unconscious**".

So, "**He passed out**" means "**he was unconscious**".

I think my sentence is ok, if I say "**he lying *unconscious* on the floor**".

But. now, I don't want to use the adjective "**unconscious**". I want to use the verb "**to pass out**".

Is "**he lying *passing out* on the floor**" more or less equivalent to "**he lying *unconscious* on the floor**"?

Comment: As a general rule, do not have 2 words in a row that have "ing" at the end.

Answer (score 3):

The thing that seems wrong to me about this is the verb 'passing'. To 'pass out' means to slip into unconsciousness. It can mean to faint. That happens in a moment. If he's already on the floor, it's an event in the past. He's *passed out*.

You could say:

- He is lying passed out on the floor.
- He is passed out on the floor.
- He is on the floor, passed out.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, "He is lying passed out on the floor,"or just, "He's passed out on the floor."

Comment: Is "**he is passed out on the floor**" valid as "**passed** here is an adjective"? Because in the dictionary, one example says "**He drank until he passed out.**" and "**passed**" here is a verb.

Comment: I would describe"passed out" as an idiom meaning "unconscious" in the phrase, "He is passed out."  But when you say, "He passed out," you're saying he went unconscious.

Comment: 'He is lying passing out' would mean that he is in the act of becoming unconscious at this moment, which is presumably not what you mean.